# numpy argmin vectorization

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to iterate over numpy rows, and put the index of each cluster of 3 elements that contains the lowest value into another row. This should be in the context of left, middle, right; the left and right edges only look at two values ('left and middle' or 'middle and right'), but everything in the middle should look at all 3.

For loops do this trivially, but it's very slow. Some kind of numpy vectorization would probably speed this up.

For example:

```
 [1 18 3 6 2]
 # should give the indices...
 [0 0 2 4 4] # matching values 1 1 3 2 2
```

Slow for loop of an implementation:

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        i = 0 if x == 0 else x - 1
        other_array[y,x] = np.argmin(array[y,i:x+2]) + i
```

Comment: This is a good candidate for stride trick

Comment: In the real data how many rows and columns?  Iterating on columns might be faster.

Comment: It's dynamic. Could be more of one than the other for any given data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** See update below for a solution with no `for` loops.

This works for an array of any number of dimensions:

```
def window_argmin(arr):
    padded = np.pad(
        arr,
        [(0,)] * (arr.ndim-1) + [(1,)],
        'constant',
        constant_values=np.max(arr)+1,
    )
    slices = np.concatenate(
        [
            padded[..., np.newaxis, i:i+3]
            for i in range(arr.shape[-1])
        ],
        axis=-2,
    )
    return (
        np.argmin(slices, axis=-1) + 
        np.arange(-1, arr.shape[-1]-1)
    )
```

The code uses `np.pad` to pad the last dimension of the array with an extra number to the left and one to the right, so we can always use windows of 3 elements for the argmin. It sets the extra elements as max+1 so they'll never be picked by argmin.

Then it uses an `np.concatenate` of a list of slices to add a new dimension with each of 3-element windows. This is the only place we're using a `for` loop and we're only looping over the last dimension, once, to create the separate 3-element windows. (See update below for a solution that removes this `for` loop.)

Finally, we call `np.argmin` on each of the windows.

We need to adjust them, which we can do by adding the offset of the first element of the window (which is actually -1 for the first window, since it's a padded element.) We can do the adjustment with a simple sum of an `arange` array, which works with the broadcast.

Here's a test with your sample array:

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 18,  3,  6,  2])

>>> window_argmin(x)

array([0, 0, 2, 4, 4])
```

And a 3d example:

```
>>> z

array([[[ 1, 18,  3,  6,  2],
        [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
        [ 3,  6, 19, 19,  7]],

       [[ 1, 18,  3,  6,  2],
        [99,  4,  4, 67,  2],
        [ 9,  8,  7,  6,  3]]])

>>> window_argmin(z)

array([[[0, 0, 2, 4, 4],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 0, 1, 4, 4]],

       [[0, 0, 2, 4, 4],
        [1, 1, 1, 4, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]]])
```

---

**UPDATE:** Here's a version using [stride_tricks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) that doesn't use any `for` loops:

```
def window_argmin(arr):
    padded = np.pad(
        arr,
        [(0,)] * (arr.ndim-1) + [(1,)],
        'constant',
        constant_values=np.max(arr)+1,
    )
    slices = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        padded,
        shape=arr.shape + (3,),
        strides=padded.strides + (padded.strides[-1],),
    )
    return (
        np.argmin(slices, axis=-1) + 
        np.arange(-1, arr.shape[-1]-1)
    )
```

What helped me come up with the stride tricks solution was [this numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7753) asking to add a sliding window function, linking to an [example implementation of it](https://gist.github.com/nils-werner/9d321441006b112a4b116a8387c2280c), so I just adapted it for this specific case. It's still pretty much magic to me, but it works.

Tested and works as expected for arrays of different numbers of dimensions.

Comment: That's brilliant. I've been trying to wrap my head around stride_tricks for a while now.

Comment: @JohnLaughlin Thanks! What helped me come up with the stride tricks solution was [this numpy issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7753) asking to add a sliding window function, linking to an [example implementation of it](https://gist.github.com/nils-werner/9d321441006b112a4b116a8387c2280c), so I just adapted it for this specific case. It's still pretty much magic to me as well 

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
array = [1, 18, 3, 6, 2]
array.insert(0, np.max(array) + 1)     # right shift of array
# [19, 1, 18, 3, 6, 2]

other_array = [ np.argmin(array[i-1:i+2]) + i - 2 for i in range(1, len(array)) ]

array.remove(np.max(array))            # original array
# [1, 18, 3, 6, 2]
```

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner than a for loop, but is still as slow. I think numpy operations may be needed here.